# Инкремент в bat-нике

Tags: bat, инкремент

Предусловие:
есть два png файла, которые сравниваются попиксельно(использую утилиту ImageMagick) и результат сравнения выводится в третий файл. Для двух файлов просто сделать вручную сравнение или через батник вызова утилиты с указанием файлов для сравнения. Но если таких файлов несколько сотен, то задача усложняется

Суть задачи:
Как реализовать в батнике инкремент для части имени файла, например, имеем строку

```
compare.exe e:\Tests\no_zoffset\vds_00000#0!T1.png e:\Tests\z_offset\vds_00000#0!T1.png -compose src e:\Tests\Test_Job\Compare\vds_00000#0!T1.png
```

необходимо, чтобы файл(пусть будет compare.bat) заполнился такими же строками только с +1 к каждой из частей где есть `00000` (`vds_00000#`).

Либо возможно другое решение, вызывать в цикле выполнение вышеуказанной строки, но снова-таки с инкрементом в +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На обычном PowerShell, доступном ещё со времен Windows XP:

```powershell
New-Alias image-compare 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\compare.exe';

$noZOffsetPath = 'e:\Tests\no_zoffset';
$zOffsetPath = 'e:\Tests\z_offset';
$resultPath = 'e:\Tests\Test_Job\Compare';

$range = 1..5000;
$format = 'vds_000000!T1\.png';

foreach($i in $range) {
    $name = $i.ToString($format);

    Write-Output "Comparing $name";
    image-compare $noZOffsetPath\$name $zOffsetPath\$name $resultPath\$name; 
}
```

В BAT-файлах это реализуется далеко не так прямолинейно.

Да и в общем-то BAT-файлы для автоматизации задач в Windows практически "умерли" ещё в середине 2000-х. Язык не развивается, да и отжившее своё консольные утилиты, Microsoft постепенно удаляет из состава ОС. Советую перейти на PowerShell - он простой и довольно приятный в обращении.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Это то что нужно! Ну и также спасибо за указание в каком направлении дальше развиваться. Правда приятнее чем на батнике.